# Why people comment instead of answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

There so many answers in SO posted as comments (just [yet another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237404/how-to-use-stl-map)). Why people don't follow the correct thread flow and answer, when they got the solution right? I think answers are a lot easier to track and contemplate and, additionally, give the person asking question the power to accept the correct solution.

Is there a way to convert a comment in an answer if you think this is appropriate?

Comment: Sometimes I feel that what I have to add doesn't qualify as a full answer.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36660/commenting-instead-of-answering?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

People don't always know for certain that the comment is answering the question, in particular when there could be several different possible solutions.

Additionally, sometimes, if an answer is trivial enough to be answered in a comment, it suggest that the question wasn't a good question for SO.

Answer (score 3):

Some answers are *that* trivial that it is sometimes not even worth posting an answer and the question should probably be closed as "localized".