# Semantic differences between commenting and answering

Tags: discussion, comments

According to the rules and various statements, **comments** are for clarification, while **answers** are...well...answers.

However, in various questions, I have seen answers given directly in comments. Sometimes, these answers are long, and sometimes they are short. I have also seen short answers as **answers**, so there is definitely a situational difference.

I looked into [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36660/commenting-instead-of-answering) thread, but I still do not understand the semantic difference between the two. Anyone can explain this?

Comment: Comments are usually used to answer a question when the commenter a) doesn't think the question should remain (it's a likely dupe, it is low-quality, ...) b) isn't exactly certain whether or not they are actually right or c) believes there needs to be a more elaborate answer than the comment they give (as in: the comment is a hint where an answerer may wish to look for a full solution). - In this case, I'm fairly certain there's a dupe somewhere.

Comment: Related: [Comments have become answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143514/comments-have-become-answers). The question not so much, but the answers there, definitely.

Comment: In meta, questions can be answered also by comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen this many times, especially on Meta.

*(You'll have to trust me with this assertion, because I'm not going to go and trawl for examples or name names...)* Usually these answers are left by high rep individuals. They are interested in helping someone but due to circumstances, i.e.:

- not looking for (more meaningless) rep
- too busy
- don't expect the question to survive
- haven't got time to dig out supporting references that a good answer should have
- haven't got the time (or inclination) to select the appropriate duplicate (from potentially 100's) in order to close the question

they tender the answer as a comment.

**Are they throw-away answers?** Not really, they are still perfectly valid and correct.

**Do we want to encourage this habit?** Probably not, but nor should we stomp on it.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on the site, but on non-meta sites, I think "answers" as comments come in 2 different flavors.

1. Question that should be closed but someone wants to help out the OP before or after the question gets closed
2. I don't know the answer and just have a guess, so I leave it as a comment instead.

For meta sites, it is usually just a short answer or link and not worth a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for me is because I don't want to be downvoted for feeding a help vampire. However, if you're referring to [meta] as well, it's probably because people don't understand that saying "-1 ..." in a comment could easily well be an a swer explaining *why* they don't want the proposal to succed.

Look at [FEichinger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190617/semantic-differences-between-commenting-and-answering#comment591221_190617)'s comment. That could very wel be an answer here IMHO.