# Should I accept answers in these scenarios?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I'll give you four examples

1) [this](https://superuser.com/questions/685638/every-website-is-showing-untrusted-certificate-warning-on-all-browsers/685696?noredirect=1#685696), a user commented on my question, he solved it and then someone else 2 hours later, said the same as an answer, although I'm so grateful to all the members in this great community, I don't know if I should give the guy who answered any credits/reputation, the guy who commented might think it's unfair and i think that.

2) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364893/linking-a-sound-file-to-a-string-value), I haven't had time to test the answer, should an answer be accepted, if not tested by the asker?

3) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104366/how-to-get-the-row-size-and-the-column-of-an-array-in-common-lisp), I don't really know common lisp, so I don't know which answer is better, I upvoted all anwers without accepting any.

And the last senario would be if I'm asking for an opinion, lets say on Chess.SE, I asked which opening is better and I got more than a great answer

Comment: As a general rule commenting an answer is saying; I don't have time to format this as a full answer, if anyone else wants to; go for it. In other words treat answers as if the comments weren't there.

Comment: Accepting is completely optional, you don't *have* to accept any. As for 2), I wouldn't accept it if you haven't tested it yet. What if it doesn't work..?

Comment: Also; try to keep to one question per question. In this case I've comment answered because im only answering one of your questions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Accept the answer. You comment only, you lose the rep and other bonuses. (It's well documented around Meta Stack Overflow; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95755/223030), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4217/223030), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190617/223030)...)
2. Wait until you've tested. Accepting is meant to mean "works best for the asker"; that's you. How will you know if it's best if you haven't tested it?
3. Can't give any general case solutions, but as a Common Lisp-er I'd recommend [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20105115/1053021).
4. Again, accepting means that answer was *best for you*. Choose the best one for you!